# Appium: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='q']"}

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, appium, appium-android

I am new trying to transition to Mobile Automation testing using appium, i get an error when i try to sendKeys to the search field in chrome browser on Android studio (virtual device) stating: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='q']"}

Comment: driver.get("https://google.com");
   //System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
   
        Set<String> contexts=driver.getContextHandles();   
          for(String contextName :contexts)
        {
   System.out.println(contextName);
       }
        driver.context("WEBVIEW_chrome");
   
   Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("What is Appium");
         driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class MobileBrowserTest extends BrowserBaseTest2 { 
@Test
 public void MobileBrowserDemo() 
 {
driver.get("http://google.com"); System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
WebDriverWait w= new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));       w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("q")));
 driver.findElement(name("q")).sendKeys("What is Appium?");driver.findElement(name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
}
}